# How to get the length of a recorded sound in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I try to automate a PowerPoint presentation. It should change the slide automatically after the duration of the recorded and embedded sound. I tried it with ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(1).AnimationSettings.SoundEffect but there were no option to get a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I just have to do it with: ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("test").MediaFormat.Length